# I am working with PHP and have an Array of Arrays that looks something like this :

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, array-merge

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Title
            [2] => Exam1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => class_name
            [2] => date
            [3] => start_time
            [4] => finish_time
            [5] => subject
            [6] => exam_details
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2014-03-08
            [3] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [4] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [5] => Maths
            [6] => Extra comments
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2014-03-07
            [3] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [4] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [5] => Eng
            [6] => Extra comments
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2014-03-06
            [3] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [4] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [5] => Science
            [6] => Extra comments
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [1] => Title
            [2] => Exam2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [1] => class_name
            [2] => date
            [3] => start_time
            [4] => finish_time
            [5] => subject
            [6] => exam_details
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2014-03-08
            [3] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [4] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [5] => Maths
            [6] => Extra comments
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2014-03-07
            [3] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [4] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [5] => Eng
            [6] => Extra comments
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2014-03-06
            [3] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [4] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [5] => Science
            [6] => Extra comments
        )

)
```

As you can see, there are some Title and title name in the first  array and second array define field name and other three is value of that field , I would like to divide array using exam title ,like this

```
[Exam1] =>Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [class_name] => 10
            [date] => 2014-03-08
            [start_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [finish_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [subject] => Maths
            [exam_details] => Extra comments
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class_name] => 10
            [date] => 2014-03-07
            [start_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [finish_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [subject] => Eng
            [exam_details] => Extra comments
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [class_name] => 10
            [date] => 2014-03-06
            [start_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [finish_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [subject] => Science
            [exam_details] => Extra comments
        )
)
[Exam2] =>Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [class_name] => 10
            [date] => 2014-03-08
            [start_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [finish_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [subject] => Maths
            [exam_details] => Extra comments
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [class_name] => 10
            [date] => 2014-03-07
            [start_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [finish_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [subject] => Eng
            [exam_details] => Extra comments
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [class_name] => 10
            [date] => 2014-03-06
            [start_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [finish_time] => 2014-03-26 08:44:15
            [subject] => Science
            [exam_details] => Extra comments
        )

)
```

Comment: How are you generating the original array?

Comment: What kind of problem do You have?

Comment: using Excel file in that first row contain Exam title and second row define fields name than list of Exam.and i want to add multiple Exam in one file.

Answer (score 0):

```
// split array into small chunks
$arrChunked = array_chunk($myArray, 5);

$formattedArray = array();

// loop through array chunk
foreach ($arrChunked as $arr)
{
    // get titles
    $title = current($arr);
    $title = $title[2];

    // get key from this title
    $key = key($arr);

    // remove title from array
    unset($arr[$key]);

    // get the array without titles and append to new formatted array
    $formattedArray[$title] = $arr;
}
```

Ref. for [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the logic, I haven't tested it.

Save your result to a new array say $array.

```
// Generate result set
$i=0;
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if(count($arr)==2) {
        $i++;
        $newarray[$i] = array();
    } else {
        foreach($arr as $single){
            array_push($newarray[$i], $single);
        }
    }
}

// New result array
foreach($newarray as $a_new) {
    print_r($a_new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok

Try that way :)

```
$badArray = array();
$goodArray = array();

$i = FALSE;
$k = FALSE;

foreach($badArray as $key=>$value){
    if( !empty($value[1] && $value[1] === 'Title')){
        $i = TRUE;
        $k = $value[2];
        $goodArray[$value[2]] = [];
        continue;
    }

    if( $i == TRUE){
        $i = FALSE;
        $keysArray = $value;
        continue;
    }

    $goodArray[$k][] = array_combine(array_values($keysArray), array_values($value));
}


echo "<pre>";

var_dump($goodArray);
```

I think I got the correct answer but better check it :)